# Dagger 2 Inject generic interface implementations

Tags: java, android, generics, dagger-2

I would like to inject implementations of my generic interface via constructor.

This is my interface

```
public interface BaseValidator<T> {
    boolean isValid(T t);
}
```

First Implementation

```
public class FirstValidator implements BaseValidator<String> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(String string) {
    // code here
}
```

Second Implementation

```
public class SecondValidator implements BaseValidator<Int> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(Int int) {
    // code here
}
```

My provides in validation module

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("FirstValidator")
public BaseValidator<String> provideFirstValidator(){
    return new FirstValidator();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("SecondValidator")
public BaseValidator<Int> provideSecondValidator(){
    return new SecondValidator();
}
```

And then when I try to inject it like this

```
private BaseValidator<String> mFirstValidator;

@Inject
public MainPresenter(@Named("FirstValidator") BaseValidator<String> firstValidator) {
    this.mFirstValidator = firstValidator;
}
```

It throws error

```
error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] BaseValidator<java.lang.String> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

How can I inject my implementations of generic interface to any class?

Comment: @Boken how did you solve this. I am facing a similar problem

Comment: Have you solved this?